# CKEditor clearing all SESSION vars

Tags: php, ckeditor, session-variables

I am using CKEditor in the backend of a website and stragely enought it wipes all of the SESSION vars when it gets loaded... I have no clue as to why this happens.

I have used it before and it's never done this. Nothing seems to be new or changed from previous times it was used.

Any idea what it could be? Could it be server-specific?

Thank you.

Comment: I very much doubt CKEditor wipes anything on server side. My guess is you're loading it from a location where the session doesn't carry. Can you show some code?

Comment: It does because removing it solves the SESSION problem and only pages where CKEditor is used wipe the SESSION vars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What a load of crap... the reason for this is specifying:
`$config['contentsCss']=array('inexistent.css','existent.css');`
Where inexistent.css does not exist and existent.css does...

That makes a lot of sense, if you can't find a CSS file just flush the whole $_SESSION variables.

Comment: I think that I've seen a comment like that in some other place: when a non-existing file is requested, the server has some strange security that destroys the current session variables. I don't understand how that can be seen as a security measure, but now you should be able to find out who's the real culprit.

Comment: This is really weird behaviour, but as @Alfonso says definitely server related. Could it be that there is a custom 404 page wiping the session?

Comment: Hi, Pekka and Alfonso. There is no 404 that does that, however, if it is server related it's very odd. I have requested files in PHP either with request or include and if they did not exist, the SESSION would not get cleared, just an error shown on screen. I wonder how CKEditor requests the css files.